# What's the best way to differentiate Users from Groups of Users using icons?

Tags: gui-design, icons

Think admin panels.

I am using an icon with 2 persons (like [image: this]) to indicate the "user management" section of an app I'm developing.

However, client has asked me to enable **group creation** (as in being able to group users together in arbitrary groups) but I've no idea what icon I should use, since that icon I've just shown would be ideal for it but then what would I use for "users"?

I thought perhaps a composition could work but... well, any suggestions on how to represent **users** and **groups of users** at the same time?

**P.S.:** oh yeah, that icon is from fatcow hosting set.

Comment: Conventionally it's three people for a user group icon.

Comment: Hi.  I'm afraid that as per our [FAQ] icon request questions are off topic for this site. There is no correct answer to this type of question. This has been discussed [on our meta site](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/629/is-it-time-to-put-an-end-to-icon-for-x-questions) in the past so should give you an indication as to why, and what you can do to ask more relevant UX topics here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a **single-person** icon for user and the **two-person** icon for group?

> [image: user] user.png
>
> [image: group] group.png

Depending how groups function within the application, you could use a **folder** icon to represent groups. This is how Microsoft sometimes chooses to present groups (e.g., think Active Directory).

> [image: folder_user] folder_user.png

There's also a **three-person icon** in that set that could be used for group management:

> [image: reseller_programm] reseller_programm.png

In all cases, I would recommend using the single-person icon for users to make it distinct from the [new] concept of groups.

Comment: 'Folder user' is PERFECT. Better conceptual representation than "groups", and crystal clear to boot!

Comment: With the folder_user I would rather think it's my personal folder. Though in the context, it might be perfectly clear it has something to do with groups.